# SSIS connection test works but package errors with Error : Failed to acquire connection

Tags: sql-server, ssis, connection

We have a variety of SSIS solutions which we develop and test in Visual Studio 2019. We recently got a new development server installed (SQL 2016)

When we open a solution we now need to go through a process of testing the project connections before opening a package as otherwise the connections from the package show as offline.

The main problem is that although the 'test connection' works to our SQL server databases, packages will not run against the new development server. We just get an error

'[Execute SQL Task] Error: Failed to acquire connection "PKD-SQL-DEVDW_DW.AGIDU". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.'

Looking at the SQL profiler the test connects by doing a login using our windows login but when running a package there is nothing reaching the server - i.e. nothing showing any connection to the server at all.

We can run a package against the new development server if we call it from a SQL agent job, and we can run successfully against the live server.

Is there some configuration of our new development server/instance that needs tweaking to allow Visual Studio packages to connect. We are stumped by this problem. Any help/advice much appreciated

Thanks

Phil

Comment: When you say the connection fails when you run the packages, is that in debug in visual studio?  How are the packages configured?  If you are using parameters, make sure the defaults in the package and project pointing to the new server.  Those values will be picked up when you run it in debug.

Comment: Hi Mark, yes we are debugging from VS, executing an individual task or package and cannot connect to the new server. The server has the same name as the old one so we have changed nothing in the packages. The connections are setup as project connections which we then reference in each package.